# Need to redirect to another form after devise sign up form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

i am new to ror..i have created a form using devise..the registeration form is working..the values are saved in db too but after saving it redirects to users page...Is there any way to change it...i want another form to be link once user submits form...

**Controller**

```rb
class UserRequestsController < ApplicationController
  def new
   @user_request = UserRequest.new
  end
end
```

**Application Helper**

```rb
def resource_name
  :user
end

def resource
  @resource ||= User.new
end

def devise_mapping
  @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
end
```

**Model**

```
class UserRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validates :user_id, :email, :name, :invitation_type, presence: true
  validates :email, uniqueness: true
  validates :email, email: true
  validate :email_not_in_use_already
  validate :invitation_type_is_valid

  def email_not_in_use_already
    if new_record? && User.where(email: self.email).any?
      errors.add(:email, "is already in use")
    end
  end

  def invitation_type_is_valid
    unless INVITATION_TYPES.include?(self.invitation_type)
      errors.add(:invitation_type, "is not a valid type of invitation")
    end
  end
end
```

**Application Controller**

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
      u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :time_zone, :terms_of_service)
    end

    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) do |u|
      u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :time_zone, :terms_of_service)
    end
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    previous_url = session[:previous_url]

    # if user has an invite code and isn't set up yet, direct them to the appropriate creation page
    if invited_user_needs_profile?(session[:hash_code])
      return path_for_invite(session[:hash_code])
    end

    user = resource # not checking resource type since right now only one is User; add later if needed

    # require acceptance of terms of service
    unless user.terms_of_service == true
      flash[:alert] = "You have not yet accepted the Terms of Service. Please verify your account information and review the Terms of Service."
      return edit_user_registration_path
    end

    # redirect to previous URLs in case user followed a link or bookmark but they were redirected due to needing to log in
    unless Rails.env == "test"
      # don't redirect to previous url if it's going to the root or users_path, because in those cases we'd rather take the user to their home page
      return previous_url if previous_url.present? && previous_url != root_path && previous_url != new_user_registration_path && !(previous_url =~ /\/users\/password/)
    end

    if user.planner.present?
      planner_path(user.planner.id)
    elsif user.vendor.present?
      vendor_path(user.vendor.id)
    else
      root_path
    end
  end

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    root to: "vendors#invited_new", as: :manager_root
  end
end
```

Need to redirect to another controller action...can u please give any idea to get it fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify only the path name there. Change:

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    root to: "vendors#invited_new", as: :manager_root
end
```

to:

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    manager_root_path
end
```

Read the [docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in):

```
def stored_location_for(resource)
  nil
end

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  # path_to_redirect_to For eg. root_path
end
```

Comment: already i have added in application controller                                                               
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
   root to: "vendors#invited_new", as: :manager_root
 end  ...but still it doesn't redirect

Comment: can you show your complete ApplicationController.rb code?

Comment: have added application controller code ..please check

Comment: check my updated answer. after the change, restart your server.

Comment: still its not redirecting to new path...it redirects to user page only

Comment: try Lalitharyani suggestion below

Answer (score 1):

Yon can override your devise registration controller

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  ##this method calls when signup is success
    def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      if put your condition here
        your_redirect_path (replace your different controller path here)
      else
        root_path
      end
    end 

end
```

In this method you just write your logic

Or you can do one thing in your registrations controller create method after your resource will be saved

```
if resource.save
  if resource.active_for_authentication?
    if your condition 
      respond_with resource, location: your_redirect_path
    else
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Make a new controller "registrations_controller.rb" and customize the appropriate method:**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    '/an/example/path' # Or :prefix_to_your_route
  end
end
```

**If the account that is registered is confirmable and not active yet, you have to override after_inactive_sign_up_path_for method.**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    '/an/example/path' # Or :prefix_to_your_route
  end
end
```

**2. Modify config/routes.rb to use the new controller
  Modify your devise_for line in routes.rb to look like this.**

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }
```

**Optionally Copy Views**

Note: In rails 3.2.5 running Ruby 1.9.2-p290 the steps below don't seem to be necessary. You just need to create your RegistrationsController and alter your routes. Then, by virtue of inheriting from Devise::RegistrationsController, you pick up the existing Devise registrations views. This holds regardless of whether you've created those views already with

```
rails g devise:views
```

or not.

Note: After changing the controller in the config/routes.rb file, you will want to copy over the devise registration views over to the new app/views/registrations path.

Copy the files using "rails generate devise:views". After doing this, you need to copy views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb to views/registrations/new.html.erb Otherwise you will get a "Missing Template" error when you go to users/sign_up

**3. Modify config/application.rb**

> You might need this line in case you encounter "MissingTemplate" error
>   in "/users/sign_up" page.

```
config.paths['app/views'] << "app/views/devise"
```